# Is there any example of nef and big divisor whose multiples are not movable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose $X/\mathbb{C}$ is a normal, projective variety. Is there a $\mathbb Q$-Cartier $\mathbb Q$-divisor $D$, such that $D$ is nef and big, but for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, the linear system $|mD|$ is not movable (i.e. the fixed part of the linear system is codimension 1)?

If just requiring $D$ is big, there are plenty of such examples. Moreover, because of base point free theorem, $X$ cannot be Fano type, Calabi-Yau type, etc. However, I believe such example should exist, but I don't know how to cook up one.

Comment: There are such examples even in dimension 2. See the positivity book by Lazarsfeld, Example 2.3.3-2.3.5, Page 160-161.